# Unequal join with 2 time ranges

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 tables,

The first one is a room availability table which comprises:

1. blocking start/end
2. my lease of the room start/end

   | room_id | bk_start | bk_end | lease_start | lease_end |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | abc | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-05 | 2023-03-01 | 2023-03-31 |
   | abc | 2023-03-12 | 2023-03-14 | 2023-03-01 | 2023-03-31 |
   | cba | 2023-04-01 | 2023-04-02 | 2023-03-01 | 2023-05-31 |

The second table is a time dimension table, like

| date | day_of_week | is_holiday |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 2 | true |
| 2023-01-02 | 3 | false |
| .... |  |  |
| 2024-01-01 | 3 | true |

What I wanna join them to make the granularity of output becomes "per room per day" between its lease and also label if the room is blocked on that date, as shown at the end.

I tried `unequal join`, like

```
select ..., case
        when date between bk_start and bk_end
        then 1 else 0  
    end as is_blocked
from 
  table_a a 
join table_b b
ON a.date >= b.lease_start 
    AND a.date <= nvl(b. lease_end,'2999-01-01')
```

for room "cba", it's ok but for room "abc", it will generate 2 rows for each day. Particularly on blocking date, for is_blocked, one row is "true" and one row is "false".

How to use sql to achieve that? I am using spark-sql.
Any help is appreciated.

Expected result example:

| date | day_of_week | is_blocked |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-01 | abc | false |
| 2023-03-02 | abc | false |
| 2023-03-03 | abc | true |
| 2023-03-04 | abc | true |
| ... |  |  |
| 2023-03-14 | abc | true |
| .... |  |  |
| 2023-03-31 | abc | false |
| 2023-03-01 | cba | false |
| .... |  |  |
| 2023-04-02 | cba | true |
| .... |  |  |
| 2023-05-31 | cba | false |